# Injecting Service Providers in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In the AngularJS 2.0 Heroes tutorial explanation it states that if a child component includes a service in its @Component Providers list, then Angular will create a separate instance of that service specific to the child.  What I don't understand is what you would do if sometimes you wanted to use the child component independently, and other times within a parent component. This seems like a severe restriction.  I've just playing with Angular 2.0, so most likely I've misunderstood something.

Here's the explanation from the Angular.io site from the Services section of the Heroes Tutorial.

> Appendix: Shadowing the parent's service
>
> We stated earlier that if we injected the parent AppComponent
>   HeroService into the HeroDetailComponent, we must not add a providers
>   array to the HeroDetailComponent metadata.
>
> Why? Because that tells Angular to create a new instance of the
>   HeroService at the HeroDetailComponent level. The HeroDetailComponent
>   doesn't want its own service instance; it wants its parent's service
>   instance. Adding the providers array creates a new service instance
>   that shadows the parent instance.
>
> Think carefully about where and when to register a provider.
>   Understand the scope of that registration. Be careful not to create a
>   new service instance at the wrong level.

[Here's the link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html#!#shadow-provider) to the page this came from to put it in context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a Component to have its own instance of a Service and at the same time to have an instance of its parent's service you have to take a look at [`@SkipSelf()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/SkipSelf-decorator.html)

Consider the following code

```js
class Service {
    someProp = 'Default value';
}

@Component({
  providers : [Service] // Child's instance
})
class Child {
  constructor(
    @SkipSelf() parentSvc: Service, 
    svc: Service
    ) {
        console.log(pSvc.someProp); // Prints 'Parents instance'
        console.log(svc.someProp);  // Prints 'Default value'
    }
}

@Component({
  providers : [Service] // Parent's instance
})
class Parent {
  constructor(svc: Service) {
    svc.someProp = 'Parent instance';
  }
}
```

With `@SkipSelf()` we are telling the component to start the dependency resolution from the parent injector (the name `SkipSelf` says a lot, I guess).

You can read more about visibility in [Host and Visibility in Angular 2's Dependency Injection](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/20/host-and-visibility-in-angular-2-dependency-injection.html) from @PascalPrecht.

Check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kq8tzHtUg6X0k59qnUzN?p=preview) with a working example.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured there was something I just hadn't seen yet.

Comment: @SkipSelf link above is 404